# A classic design and a trivial issue with UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios5, storyboard

I feel like an idiot, because i fight with something, that should be very straighforward, but there is a hidden sabouteur in my Xcode somewhere.

The UI is built in StoryBoard.

I have a modal view, that contains an upper UINavigationBar and a UIScrollView...inside a scrollview are some textfields.
Now I understand that when I start to edit a text in textfield, a keyboard pops out. Thats ok. I am tracking that moment via NotificationCenter.

```
[notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

I am calling a selector when that happens

```
 -(void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
  {
    ... code changing the frame
  }
```

Of course, I need to resize the scrollview to make room for the keyboard, but AS SOON AS I attach a newly created  CGRect "frame" value of scrollview's frame,  the scrollview does NOT resize according to my wishes, but instead takes a size of a vieconntroller's view minus the statusbar's 44 pixels..

I lost a few hours on this already and it drives me nuts. Can you help?

Comment: please show your code, where you set the new frame…

Comment: I second the motion. Post the code where you change the frame? of the UIScrollView. Also, is the scrollview in a UIView or is it the main view of the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: why do you need to change the frame of the scrollview? The keyboard just appears above everything anyway. Perhaps a more convenient way to catch the editing BTW is the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, but I guess your way is fine too.

Second: if you want to modify the view that is the view controller's `view` property, you cannot change the frame. It is the full screen (minus status bar, minus nav bar if any) by default. If you want to dynamically resize a view it has to be a subview of `self.view`.

Comment: I need the same behavior as in the modal view, that shows up when you add a new event to calendar in iOS5 on iPhone. My modal view also has  more textfields, than a physical screen can show at the same time.

Comment: So best use a simple grouped table view and show it modally. I still do not see why you would like to change the frame. Maybe you mean the `contentOffset`?